# Phonegap: unable to write files to disk

Tags: android, cordova, io, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am trying to record audio in android in `.wav` format (uncompressed). I am developing a phonegap application, so I used the already available plugin here - https://github.com/petrica/wav-recorder

I imported the plugin as it says. Below is my index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <!-- <script src="js/app.js"></script> -->
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for PhoneGap to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // Record audio
    // 


    // PhoneGap is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        //recordAudio();
        //playAudio();
        recordWav();
    }

    // status callback 
var statusCallback = function (mediaStatus, error)
{
  if (martinescu.Recorder.STATUS_ERROR == mediaStatus) {
    alert(error);
  }
}

// buffer callback
var bufferCallback = function (buffer)
{
  console.log(buffer);
}

function recordWav()
{
    var recorder = new martinescu.Recorder('/record1234556.wav', { sampleRate: 22050 }, statusCallback, bufferCallback);
    recorder.record();

     // Stop recording after 10 sec
        var recTime = 0;
        var recInterval = setInterval(function() {
            recTime = recTime + 1;
            setAudioPosition(recTime + " sec");
            if (recTime >= 10) {
                clearInterval(recInterval);
             recorder.stop();

            }
        }, 1000);
}

    // onSuccess Callback
    //
    function onSuccess() {
        console.log("recordAudio():Audio Success");
    }

    // onError Callback 
    //
    function onError(error) {
        alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' + 
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }

    // Set audio position
    // 
    function setAudioPosition(position) {
        document.getElementById('audio_position').innerHTML = position;
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>
          <title>Device Properties Example</title>
          <!-- <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.4.1.js"></script> -->
          <p id="media">Recording audio...</p>
          <p id="audio_position"></p>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
</html>
```

But the issue is, I am unable to run this, because I am getting the error 02-18

```
02-18 13:43:30.899: E/ro.martinescu.audio.ExtAudioRecorder(21158): /record1234556.wav: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
```

I tried just `record1234556.wav` instead of `/record1234556.wav` then it says the below error

```
02-18 13:44:18.229: E/ro.martinescu.audio.ExtAudioRecorder(21569): /storage/emulated/0record1234556.wav: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Below is my AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="10000" android:versionName="1.0.0" package="com.phonegap.helloworld" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
</manifest>
```

What is really wrong here?